# Why isn't SQL Server letting me store '21/04/17' as a date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I've got a table that currently has all columns stored as nvarchar(max), so I'm converting all the datatypes to be what they should be. I have a column of dates, however when I run this:

```
ALTER TABLE Leavers ALTER COLUMN [Actual_Termination_Date] date;
```

I get

```
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".
```

This is relatively normal, so I did the following to investigate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 [Actual_Termination_Date]
FROM LEAVERS
WHERE ISDATE([Actual_Termination_Date]) = 0
```

which returned:

```
NULL
13/04/2017
14/04/2017
17/04/2017
19/04/2017
21/04/2017
23/04/2017
24/04/2017
26/04/2017
28/04/2017
29/03/2017
29/04/2017
30/04/2017
31/03/2017
42795
42797
42813
42817
42820
42825
```

The null and excel style date formats (e.g. 42795) are no problem, however it's the ones appearing as perfectly normal dates I'm having a problem with. I usually fix issues like this by using one of the following fixes:

```
SELECT  cast([Actual_Termination_Date] - 2 as datetime)
FROM LEAVERS
WHERE ISDATE([Actual_Termination_Date]) = 0
```

or

```
SELECT  cast(convert(nvarchar,[Actual_Termination_Date], 103) - 2 as datetime)
FROM LEAVERS
WHERE ISDATE([Actual_Termination_Date]) = 0
```

When these return back the dates as I would expext, I'd then do an UPDATE statement to change them in the table and then convert the column type. However I keep getting an error message telling me that various dates can't be converted such as:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '21/04/2017' to data type int.
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Use ISO dates and forget about these problems. They take the *standard* form YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: As i warn in my answer though, @TheImpaler  , `yyyy-MM-dd` isn't safe in SQL Server. For example, on my instance, `CONVERT(datetime, '2020-03-26')` will fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because of your language setting. For `'21/04/2017'` to work, you'll need to be using the `BRITISH` language, or other language that uses `dd/MM/yyyy`. I *suspect* you are using `ENGLISH` which is actually American.

American's use `MM/dd/yyyy` meaning that `'21/04/2017'` would mean the 4th day of the 21st month in the year 2017; obviously that doesn't work.

The **best** method is to use an unambiguous format, regardless of language and data type. For SQL Server that's `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` (`yyyy-MM-dd` and `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` are **not** unambiguous in SQL Server when using the older `datetime` and `smalldatetime` data types).

Otherwise you can use `CONVERT` with a [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,'21/04/2017', 103)
```

The problem with your data, however, is that you have values that are in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` and integer values. The `int` (not `varchar`) value `42817` as a `datetime` in SQL Server is `2017-03-25`. On the other hand, if this data came from Excel then the value is `2017-03-23`. I am going to **assume** the data came from Excel, not SQL Server (because the ACE drivers have a habit of reading dates as numbers, because the thing they aren't is "ace").

You'll need to therefore convert the values to an unambiguous format first, so that'll be `yyyyMMdd`. As we have 2 different types of values, this is a little harder, but still possible:

```
UPDATE dbo.Leavers
SET Actual_Termination_Date = CONVERT(varchar(8), ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(date, Actual_Termination_Date, 103), DATEADD(DAY, TRY_CONVERT(int, Actual_Termination_Date),'18991230')), 112);
```

Then you can alter your table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Leavers ALTER COLUMN [Actual_Termination_Date] date;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c23c3225d85fd9ffd82ab776152ac95) using Michał Turczyn's DML statement.

Comment: Who knew that using standards could make interoperability easier!? ;)

Comment: It's because I *assumed* the data came from Excel, @PhilCollins . For *recent* dates the integer value is that many days after 30 December 1899.

Comment: Fixed it! Worked perfectly, thank you. I'd by lying if I fully understand the solution. I can understand everything, however I'm not 100% sure what the adding '18991230' is doing. Regardless, it's working thank you.

Comment: you're right it did. Well actually it came from an an oracle db, into an .xls file. converted into a .csv and then imported as a flat file into SSMS. Also, the language settings were US English.

Answer (score 2):

Put the column into a canonical format *first*, then convert:

```
update leavers
    set Actual_Termination_Date = try_convert(date, [Actual_Termination_Date], 103);

ALTER TABLE Leavers ALTER COLUMN [Actual_Termination_Date] date;
```

The `update` will do an implicit conversion from the date to a string.  The `alter` should be able to "undo" that implicit conversion.

Back up the table before you do this!  You are likely to discover that some dates are not valid -- that is pretty much the rule when you store dates as strings although in a small minority of cases, all date strings are actually consistently formatted.

Comment: I tried this, but it turned all the values that I have having issue with into NULL and I lost the data. Luckily I did back up the data.

Answer (score 1):

The actual date does not matter. The error happens when you try to subtract 2 from a string:

```
[Actual_Termination_Date] - 2
```

The clue comes from the error message:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '21/04/2017' **to data type int**.

To fix the problem, use [`DATEADD`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp) after the conversion:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(days, -2, convert(datetime, [Actual_Termination_Date], 103))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have inconsistent date format within your column, which is terrible.

Having wrong datatype lead to it, that's why it is so important to have proper data types on columns.

Let's investigate it a little:

```
-- some test data
declare @tbl table (dt varchar(20));
insert into @tbl values 
(NULL),
('13/04/2017'),
('14/04/2017'),
('17/04/2017'),
('19/04/2017'),
('21/04/2017'),
('23/04/2017'),
('24/04/2017'),
('26/04/2017'),
('28/04/2017'),
('29/03/2017'),
('29/04/2017'),
('30/04/2017'),
('31/03/2017'),
('42795'),
('42797'),
('42813'),
('42817'),
('42820'),
('42825');
-- here we handle one format
select convert(date, dt, 103) from @tbl
where len(dt) > 5
or dt is null
-- here we handle excel like format
select dateadd(day, cast(dt as int), '1900-01-01') from @tbl
where len(dt) = 5
```

So, as you can see you have to apply to different approaches for this task. `CASE WHEN` statement should fit here nicely, see below `SELECT`:

```
select case when len(dt) = 5 then
         dateadd(day, cast(dt as int), '1900-01-01')
       else convert(date, dt, 103) end
from @tbl
```